# Mat-select panel min-width

Tags: angular-material, angular5, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I'm trying to customize mat-select with multiple checkboxes. 
for some reason the panel get wrong min-width as below:

[image]

and I don't know where its calculating this min-width.
also I tried to add panelClass and override the min-width from this class, 
for example:

```
<mat-select #multipleSelect (selectionChange)="selectItem($event.value)" panelClass="multiple-panel" multiple>      

&.multiple-panel {
   min-width: 200px !important;
}
```

but when opening the dropdown its open with the original width (like in the pic) and after few millisecond"jump" to the custom min-width defined on the panel class.

I find the mat-select very hard to style. anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I am having this same issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can style your `mat-select` dialog box by giving a panel class (as you mentioned).

Please follow this demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matselect-style?file=src/styles.css

 to see the styled `mat-select` components.

**Reason :**

- Reason for the delay is that angular for dialog-boxes, create a `cdk-overlay-pane` inside the `cdk-overlay-container` container, So in case of `mat-select` it provides a min-width of 180px, which is overridden by our panel class in the slight delay.
- Yes, there is a slight delay in opening of dialog box and customizing its width to the specified width provided in the panel class. But the delay is acceptable in the project that i was working on. 
   So, you can find the demo for styling the `mat-select` component, as i have provided 2 components and you can modify any css properties.
- Try to use styles using `::ng-deep` or `:host >>>`,  if not finding any luck,
   please paste the styles in `style.css`.

**Update 1 :**

 Tried `css animations`, and `opacity` for making smooth opening of the `mat-select` options.

```
.panel-class-applied-on-mat-select {
  animation-name: opacityDelay !important;
  animation-duration: 0.3s !important;
}

@keyframes opacityDelay {
   0%   {opacity: 0;}
  25%  {opacity: 0;}
  50%  {opacity: 0;}
  75%  {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

**[Updated StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matselect-style-min-width-opacity-hack?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Hmmm... it is not acceptable for my project. It sucks there isn't a better solution.

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale see the updated answer, if its helpful because the opening is delayed and made smooth, and mat-select options are now opening correctly to the expected width.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Amazing idea. work for me.
but you support opening the panel only. on close its get bigger again for a second, how do you recommend to add the delay when closing the panel?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar ?

Comment: @TomerAronovsky my answer supports opening of panel as i have applied animation with the panelClass provided, because on closing panelClass animation will not work. The animation will work correctly if on opening the panel a class should be added with animation property, and on closing that class should be removed. In this case animation will work perfectly fine. So i tried the open and close events, also some other events given on the official docs of mat-select but was no luck getting handlers on opening and closing of mat-select.

Comment: @TomerAronovsky sorry for not replying earlier as i forgot to reply on this thread after trying to implement opening and closing events on the mat-select.

Comment: I will have to try your solution. I ended up fixing it by just adding .mat-select-panel {
    margin-right: -32px; } Which works pretty well.

Answer (score 5):

I used another approach.
Just added this piece of code to global style.

```
.mat-select-panel {
// some your code
  &.ng-animating {
       visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
```

You can try this solution on
[DEMO StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matselect-style-min-width-opacity-hack-tzgjuh). 
Hack with opacity did not fix jumping width when select is closing.

Comment: Can you please add more detail or working sample on https://stackblitz.com.

Comment: Great! It is work.
    `<mat-select
      panelClass="triageListOptions"`
`.triageListOptions.ng-animating {
  visibility: hidden;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Please go easy on me S.O. This is my first time contributing. :)

After debugging the console, and running into this issue. Solutions were not clear online. So I'm posting mine here in case someone else runs into this.

I found that there is a width permanently set for the *infix* class. If you unset it, and optionally add some padding to the right of the value, you'll find that will resolve the issue. Add `:host` for encapsulation when using `::ng-deep`.

**Important to Note:** *`::ng-deep` is being permanently deprecated after Angular v14.
There is a property in the `@Component()` annotation called `encapsulation` which can be used to turn off the view encapsulation for the component instead of using `::ng-deep`.*

Solution for the deprecation of `::ng-deep`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector-name',
  template: `<div>Hello World!</div>`,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [
    `
      :host mat-form-field .mat-form-field-infix {
        width: unset;
      }
      :host mat-form-field .mat-select-value {
        padding-right: 0.5rem; /* 8px */ 
        /* Alternatively, for TailwindCSS: @apply pr-2 */
      }
      :host .random-class {
         /* some encapsulated styling... */
      }
      .another-random-class {
         /* some non-encapsulated styling... */
      }
    `
  ]
})
```

Solution if you do not care about the deprecation of `::ng-deep`:

```
      :host ::ng-deep mat-form-field .mat-form-field-infix {
        width: unset;
      }
      :host ::ng-deep mat-form-field .mat-select-value {
        padding-right: 0.5rem; /* 8px */
      }
```

Comment: ::ng-deep has been deprecated for a long time, but there is still no recommended alternative, and there doesn't seem to be a known EOL. You can track this here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change viewEncapsulation to none at your component decorator.and then add following css to remove the transition effect.Have a look at viewencapsulation in angular docs https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-selector',
templateUrl: './template.html',
styleUrls: ['./template.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
//CSS
.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-select-panel.ng-animating {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue and now found the solution that fit perfectly for me. Try setting min width of the panel with ::ng-deep like this.

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
  min-width: calc(100% + 14px) !important;
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Angular V15 solution:
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-select-panel {
  min-width: calc(100% + 14px) !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this way : define a panel class for your mat-select in the code and then in the global/app styling file just add:

```
.panel-class-name .mat-select-panel {
 // add your styling here
}
```

It worked for me to add some component specific styling for material components.

Answer (score 0):

From the Angular GitHub Issues, [JoeMellon suggests this workaround](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26000#issuecomment-1517753441)

> @ly000 Same dilemma here so I spent a bit of time on achieving this the best way - we can make use of the has selector and only taget the cdk pane if its child has class mat-mdc-select-panel.

```css
 .cdk-overlay-pane:has(.mat-mdc-select-panel) { min-width: fit-content; }
```

I tried it and it did exactly what I wanted: it kept the dropdown the same size as the component that triggers it, except where the content in the dropdown was wider, then the dropdown became wider to accommodate.

The only change I did was to specify `::ng-deep`, so my result was:

```css
// Make the minimum width of a dropdown fit the content with no wrapping
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane:has(.mat-mdc-select-panel) {
    min-width: fit-content;
}
```

I'm using Angular Material 17.